# android.graphics.Point: all methods are stubs

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the Point class from `android.graphics`, but it appears that all the methods are stubs.  For example, the line

```
Point p = new Point(1, 1);
```

causes `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!`.  If I look at the bytecode for Point, I see a bunch of stubbed methods, e.g:

```
  // Method descriptor #17 (II)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public Point(int x, int y);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 5]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.graphics.Point
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: x index: 1 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: y index: 2 type: int
```

What's the deal here?  Surely they didn't ship a class that's 100% stubs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you are looking at `android.jar`. That JAR file is mostly stubs. The real implementation is on the device.

For a properly configured Android project, running in an emulator or on a device, the constructor for `android.graphics.Point` and everything else will use the real implementation. You only use `android.jar` as a compilation target, and it should not be included in the resulting APK file.

Comment: I see.  I was trying to test a class using Point from a console app, which apparently isn't possible.

Comment: @Odrade: yeah, you're not going to be able to use `android.jar` for testing outside of Android. You can always grab the source code for some of the classes and put them in your own JAR, but inter-class dependencies and native methods will probably cause problems for you. Sorry!

Comment: @Odrade the solution is to subclass it like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34086643/1276636).