# Android PointF constructor not working in JUnit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I have just stumbled on this while trying to write a JUnit test. Admittedly this is my first unit test in JUnit, but I do find the behaviour very puzzling.

```
package com.example.dom.pointfbugrepro;

import android.graphics.PointF;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void pointf_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        PointF foo = new PointF(5, 0);
        assertEquals(5, foo.x, 0.0001f);
    }
}
```

Running this test in a brand new Android Project results in an assertion failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :5.0
Actual   :0.0
```

One thing I found out while investigating this problem is that assigning to the PointF instance's `x` field directly does work.

So what is the problem here? Why doesn't the constructor set the fields properly? and how should I be testing classes which use the PointF Android class?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the `PointF` object with the debugger?

Comment: @StefanBirkner Yes, it says that the fields are both '0.0'.

Comment: Could you set a break point at the first line of the constructor?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't seem like the execution reaches that break point. I have tried to step into the constructor too and the line of execution points to a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

When you run unit tests, you are using a dummy version of the android jar. Typically you will see "Method ... not mocked."exceptions, but since you are directly accessing public fields, these are simply default values.

Depending on your requirements, you could just use a fake: your own subclass extending PointF

```
    public static class FakePointF extends PointF {
        FakePointF(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

but in a more complex test you'll probably end up having to mock a whole lot of other methods.

The solution isnt pretty: you need to run instrumented tests against an emulator or device, or move to using something like Robolectric where the test runner will substitute '[shadows](http://robolectric.org/extending/)' for you.

Also see this StackOverflow answer: [android.graphics.Point: all methods are stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175421/android-graphics-point-all-methods-are-stubs).

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Is quite annoying though, wish that it would at least provide implementations of simple classes like ``PointF``.

Answer (score 1):

I was really surprised that some classes do behave like this in `JUnit` tests. I don't see any good reason for this in case of a simple `DTO` class like `Point`, but rather consider this as a nasty `Easter` egg which makes programmers' life harder. I would accept that methods like `Draw` etc. are mocked, as they can be heavily hardware-dependent, but such DTO's should not be mocked.

I'm still learning `Android` development, but the more such things I see the more I'm convinced that it is not a mature and well-thought framework.