# Float primitive magically become 0 when used to init PointF or RectF in Kotlin Android

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

See the following unit test I created:

```
import android.graphics.PointF
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test


class SimpleTest {
    data class A(val x: Float, val y: Float) {
        val origin = PointF(x, y)
        val origin1 by lazy { PointF(x, y) }
    }

    val sut = A(10f, 10f)

    @Test fun succeed() {
        assertEquals(10f, sut.x)
        assertEquals(10f, sut.y)
    }

    @Test fun failed() {
        assertEquals(10f, sut.origin.x)
        assertEquals(10f, sut.origin.y)
    }

    @Test fun failed1() {
        assertEquals(10f, sut.origin1.x)
        assertEquals(10f, sut.origin1.y)
    }
}
```

The second and third test case failed with error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :10.0
Actual   :0.0
```

Apparently, the primitive float become 0 when used to initialize `PointF`, the same applies if used to initialize `RectF`.

This error completely blow my mind, is this a bug in Kotlin?

**UPDATE:**

I have confirmed that the three test cases passed as instrumented test, which proves the stubbing of Android classes is the cause of the test failure. However, I am still observing the same issue in my application - which is not a unit test...

```
data class Viewport(val x: Float, val y: Float, val w: Int, val h: Int, val scale: Float) {
    val origin = Point2D(x, y)

    val bound = RectF(x, y, x + w * scale, y + h * scale)
    ....
 }
```

Somewhere in the application, I have logcat statement as the following:

```
Log.d(TAG, "viewport=$viewport, origin=${viewport!!.origin}, bound=${viewport!!.bound}")
```

And the logcat output I got is this:

```
01-05 12:53:17.376 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.412 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.431 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.448 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.468 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.487 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
01-05 12:53:17.501 10870-10870/com.quirklogic.ink D/Painter: viewport=Viewport(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453, w=720, h=1280, scale=1.0), origin=Point2D(x=-292.81342, y=-39.189453), bound=RectF(0.0, 0.0, 720.0, 1280.0)
```

**UPDATE2:**

I figured out it is indeed my own fault that I have altered the bound which reset it to (0, 0) origin. Not an issue with Kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android PointF constructor not working in JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010251/android-pointf-constructor-not-working-in-junit-test)

Answer (score 1):

This works for a simple self-constructed data class `PointF` without errors:

```
data class PointF(val x: Float, val y: Float)
```

The [`android.graphics.PointF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010251/android-pointf-constructor-not-working-in-junit-test) isn't working as expected here.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that it works with other data structure, but not Android's PointF and RectF. The question is: is there other classes will have the same issue and why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010251/android-pointf-constructor-not-working-in-junit-test

Comment: this not only happen in the dummy unit test but also in my application. I will see if I can replicate the same issue in instrumented test

Comment: You are right about the unit test, it is because of the stubbing, however, I am having the same issue in the real application. I have updated my question.