# Android.graphics.rect - always null

Tags: java, android, android-layout, junit, android-graphics

I want to write some tests for my Android project - and I‘m trying to instantiate a Rect()-Object in a JUnit test - but I’m always getting a null instead of the object. 
Here some examples:

```
 Rect r = new Rect(1,3,4,5);
  System.out.println(r); // -> null
  System.out.println(r.right); // -> 0
```

Comment: If r was null, r.right would throw a NullPointerException.  So r is not null.  Why do you think it is?

Comment: @GabeSechan if I print it with System.out.println like in my question above - then it prints „null“ - but yes I can access variables und methods (all intialized with standard values or return null) - this is really strange

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010251/android-pointf-constructor-not-working-in-junit-test