# Why are RectF objects empty in UnitTests

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, junit

Project:
I'm developing an Android application that matches MotionEvents to Rectangles which I defined using the RectF class.

Issue:
In my UnitTests these RectF objects are empty.
The debugger describes them as "null" and left,top,right,bottom are 0.0

My guess:
I guess AndroidStudio replaces the RectF with some empty mock (as it apparently does with other code as well). I can't verify it in another IDE currently.

UnitTest code:

```
import android.graphics.RectF
import junit.framework.TestCase
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
import org.hamcrest.core.Is.`is`
import org.junit.Test

class RectTest: TestCase() {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val rectF = RectF( -10.0F, -30F, 10F, 50F )
        assertThat( rectF.width(), `is`( 20F ) )
    }
}
```

Note that the test class is in src/test not in src/androidTest.

Comment: i'm no expert and this is mostly a guess, but the fact that it imports `android.graphics.RectF` probably means it should be an androidTest, i believe usually only business logic and just "regular" java/kotlin goes to test instead of androidTest. i think that's causing most of your issues, perhaps these getters and setters only work once this object gets used, have you moved this to androidTest to see if there's a difference ?

Comment: also, i think that your test _might_ be a bad test. you shouldn't test android libraries or functions, so perhaps the idea of testing that this object has a specific width isn't a good idea to begin with, leave android to do what it should, test your own logic or implementation. if there's a function to determine the size of this, rather test those and ensure they return what they should

Comment: I couldn't get the androidTest to run but it should run without a device so androidTest is IMO the wrong place.

Comment: the test looks bad because it's stripped down. The actual test executes my code which only uses RectF. I could also write my own RectF class but why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: the answer is that the android jar used in unit tests has these platform primitives stubbed. the implementation only exists on the device. if you try to access the member variables directly, it should throw an exception. what's still unclear to me is why. are they hardware accelerated?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010251/android-pointf-constructor-not-working-in-junit-test